# Minecraft 1.13/1.14 Crashing on Launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been trying to fix this for a while now, and I have even looked all over for solutions and have tried many things, including changing the run file think to java.exe, but my Minecraft 1.13 and 1.14 still crash on the launch either instantly, or within a minute or two. Any help I could get would be much apprectiated! Here is the crash report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006607252c, pid=14172, tid=13016
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.dll+0xd3252c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 2):

nvoglv64.dll is an nvidia driver. Try updating your video drivers to their latest version.